# Probability of wining a dice game if the sum of a pair of dices is 2 or 4 or 6

Tags: probability

> Two players, X and Y play a dice game.   A pair of dice is tossed.
>   If the sum of the dice  is 2, 4, or 6, X wins the game. Otherwise, Y
>   wins.   What is the probability that Y wins  the game?

From what i understand, we have 11 possible results for one roll :

2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 (because there is a pair of dice, so 1 won't be in the result list)

And we need either 2, or 4, or 6 to win the game, so the probability is : 3/11

I know i'm wrong!

Any helps is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sample space is small therefore, we can enumerate it as follows

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\end{array}$$

I hope the table will help you to visualize the scenario and answer the question

Comment: oh, this is so easy to understand. Thanks a heap mate!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong because there are much more possibilities for the sum to be $7$ than $3$ for example. You can roll a $7$ with $(1,6),(6,1),(2,5),(5,2),(3,4),(4,3)$ but a $3$ only with $(1,2),(2,1)$. So you are $3$ times less likely to roll a $3$.

A simple way to visualize that is by rolling the two dice one after the other. You can do $3$ only if the result of the first die is $1$ or $2$. If it is more, it's mathematically impossible to have a sum of $3$. Similarly, you can't roll a $10$ if you get $1$, $2$ or $3$ with the first die. At the opposite, if you want to roll a $7$, whatever is the result of the first die, it is possible to get the good result (if you roll a $1$, you can always roll a $6$, etc).

For your problem, you need to count every possible combination of the result of $2$ dice ($(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ being different), count the number of combination that would result in a sum of $2$, $4$ or $6$, and divide the latter by the former.

PS : Be careful when you read the question ! You should give the probability that $Y$ wins, not $X$ !

Answer (score 0):

$27/36$ = $3/4$ = $75$ percent.